# Получить значение из текста без регулярки

Tags: c#

У меня есть текст: `"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{9dff3540-fc85-4ed5-ac84-9e3c7fd8bece}\vcredist_x86.exe"  /uninstall`
Как можно получить из текста только что внутри скобок `{ }` (вместе со скобками) ? 
Не используя регулярки

Comment: Обратите внимание на комменты под ответом. На будущее, выражайтесь человеческими словами, что именно вы хотите сделать. Нужно достать GUID из пути к файлу, так и пишите. Тогда ответ будет точнее. А то получите что-то типа `Console.WriteLine(text[29..67]);` в ответе, и будете в десятках комментов выяснять, а что же на самом деле надо было.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = @"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{9dff3540-fc85-4ed5-ac84-9e3c7fd8bece}\vcredist_x86.exe";
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(str.IndexOf("{"), 38));
```

Вывод

```
{9dff3540-fc85-4ed5-ac84-9e3c7fd8bece}
```

Comment: Зачем так сложно? :) `Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(str)));`

Comment: Или даже так `Console.WriteLine(new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(str)).Name);`

Comment: Смутило просто, что автор пишет `у меня есть текст`, а не `у меня есть путь к файлу`, но вообще ваше замечание 100% валидное.

Comment: Меня смутило "вместе со скобками", так как известно, что GUID парсится и так и сяк. Но не суть, это был XY-вопрос.